# Rails 4 devise: How to log out all users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Im just about to perform an update to my app, I want to log out all users that have remembered session. I mean, once I deploy the update I want to force all the users to log in again.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're storing in active_record, just delete all the sessions.
`rake db:sessions:clear` 
If cookies, just change your session_token

Comment: Could you please add an example of "change your session_token"

Comment: In your `config/initializers/session_store.rb`, you can change your session cookie name to invalidate all sessions. `YourApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_change_me_session'`

Comment: Is there some other way? `Don't know how to build task 'db:sessions:clear' (see --tasks)`